# Vue tags input custom validation

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using vue-tags-input component. In its docs we can find [validation](http://www.vue-tags-input.com/#/examples/validation). I'm trying to create validation so valid input must have:

- min 3 signs
- two numbers
- comma between numbers

this is what I have:

```
validation: [{
    classes: 'min-length',
    rule: tag => tag.text.length < 3,
},{
    classes: 'min-length',
    rule: ({ text }) => {
        const comma = text.indexOf(',') === -1;
        if(comma) {
            const arr = text.split(',')
            if(arr[0] && arr[1]) {
                if(arr[0].typeof === 'number' && arr[1].typeof === 'number') {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}]
```

So I'm spliting string to array by `,`. In result I should have array with two elements. Then I check if both elemenets are numbers. How ever this not work properly because it treat `111` as valid but it shoudn't.

I've created [demo on codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/vue-template-wcv3i).

Comment: Are the numbers always integers? Are they always positive?

Comment: If `rule` returns true does that mean it passes or fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To check if comma exists you have to check if `indexOf` comma not equals -1.

   ```js
   const comma = text.indexOf(",") !== -1;
   ```
2. You have to convert the string to number using `Number(string)`.

   ```js
   if (typeof Number(arr[0]) === "number") {..
   ```
3. You have to return false if validation succeeds and true if there is an error,
   you are doing the opposite.

**The complete code will be:**

```js
{
  classes: "custom",
  rule: ({ text }) => {
    const comma = text.indexOf(",") !== -1;
    if (comma) {
      const arr = text.split(",");
      if (arr[0] && arr[1]) {
        if (typeof Number(arr[0]) === "number" && typeof Number(arr[1]) === "number") {
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

**A shorter regex rule will be:**

```js
{
  classes: "custom",
  rule: ({ text }) => {
    return !text.match(/^\d+,\d+$/);
  }
}
```